# How to automate control of synchronization between Maven artefact version and Git tag?

Tags: git, maven

Given the following situation:

- in a POM file in the repo root (Atlassian BitBucket) I can define that this POM has e.g. the version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
- then I can tag the codebase whatever I want like `v.0.1`.

This would be then inconsistent versioning. Is there a better/established way than some custom scripting to control sync of this?

Answer (score 2):

> then I can tag the codebase whatever I want like v.0.1

One could use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), i.e. X.Y.Z. instead of v.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) wich will take care of the sync and keep the version and tag equal. As you can read [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html)

> The `developerConnection` contains the URL of the Source Control Management system pointing to the folder containing this pom.xml This URL is prefixed with `scm:[scm-provider]` so the plugin can pick the right implementation for committing and tagging. The Maven SCM-page contains an overview all the supported SCMs, per SCM you can see how the URL should look like.